# Inserting into sorted linked list?

Tags: c#

I'm very new to coding and I couldn't understand the error in my code, I'd be very grateful for any help.

So the code works fine except for the last element because the element after that is null and I couldn't handle it (I'm very new).

The problem is with the last part.

```
public static void InsertingIntoSortedLinkedList(int value, int key)
            {
                Node m = new Node();
                m.value=value;
                m.key=key;
                if (root==null)
                {
                    m.Next = null;
                    root = m;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (key<root.key)
                    {
                        m.Next = root;
                        root = m;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Node temp1 = root;
                        Node temp2 = null;
                        while ((temp1!=null)&&(temp1.key<key))
                        {
                            temp2 = temp1;
                            temp1 = temp1.Next;
                        }
                        if (temp1==null)
                        {
                            m.Next = null;
                            temp2.Next=m;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            m.Next = temp1;
                            if (temp2!=null)//I either put this here and the last element is lost or I got a NullReferenceException. What should I change?
                            {
                                temp2.Next = m;

                            }
                        }
                    }
                }


}
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I am not sure what your problem is - I have tested your code inserting keys 10,5,20,25,2,3 & the resulting list has 6 Node elements in order 2,3,5,10,20,25 - isn't that what you want?

Comment: Could you please share your code?

Comment: I made no changes to your code at all - I just called your function 6 times with the key parameters set as I said & then checked in the debugger what was in the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One situation where you may find a problem is when you insert a value equal to the root value - those values will be skipped because you are trying to insert BEFORE the matching item and not updating the root reference.

The solution is to either insert after the matching value - this can be done by changing the line

```
while ((temp1!=null)&&(temp1.key<key))
```

to

```
while ((temp1 != null) && (temp1.key <= key))
```

OR by inserting at the root element by changing the line

```
if (key<root.key)
```

to

```
if (key <= root.key)
```

OR by updating the root value when inserting before

```
if (temp2!=null)
{
  temp2.Next = m;
}
else
  root = m;
```

Any one of the changes should fix the problem

Answer (score -4):

You have two typos:

1. `if (key<root.key)`
2. `while ((temp1!=null)&&(temp1.key<key))`

missing `>` at the end of `<key`

Comment: I don't understand this answer - show what the code should actually be

Comment: @mazury `key` is of type `int` - it is [not a generic type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/less-than-operator). `key<root.key` yields **`true` if `key` is less than `root.key`**. I agree that the spacing is not optimal, it should be `key < root.key`.